# How to extend ExpectedConditions in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

How can `protractor.ExpectedConditions` be extended in Protractor?

I tried a similar approach to how `ElementFinder` is extended:

```
function myFunction(elementFinder){
    function clientScript(e){
        return someCondition(e);
    }
    return () => browser.executeScript(clientScript, elementFinder.getWebElement());
}

protractor.ExpectedConditions.prototype.myFunction = myFunction;
```

but it fails with:

> "E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'myFunction' of undefined"

I did notice that by assigning `protractor.ExpectedConditions.myFunction` it seems to work but is that safe to do?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to extend `ExpectedConditions` instead of making a helper class and adding the function there?

Comment: Convenience? If there is a simple way to do it would be easier to use. It would be added to an in-house helper library already adding lots of locators, matchers etc.

Answer (score 0):

> yes its fault in your code, first define this

```
protractor.ExpectedConditions
```

then you cant face that error.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer but `protractor.ExpectedConditions` is defined by Protractor itself. Care to elaborate a bit?